# ELK - irregular log with multiple formats and multi line events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a trace/log of events (in form of "messages") coming from some communication equipment. My end goal is to be able to do some monitoring and analysis of the data stream coming from the equipment in (close to) real-time.

The trace is kind of a dump of the internal operation of the device and contains multiple types of events, some of which spanning multiple "messages" - I am now parsing a file (so dealing with lines) but eventually will be parsing stdin or some sort of stream.

I am expecting to get about 3 million messages an hour and have several such devices to monitor.

I currently face two challenges (just started though :-):

**Multi-message Events**

Some events appears over a few messages.

- Related messages are not necessarily consecutive.
- Usually the first message will tell that the event is segmented, how many segments to expect and includes the event identifier (key).
- The rest of the segments have the same event identifier
- The segmentation header and the other segments have their own preamble/type identifier
- The segmented messages are just "cut" in the middle and continue in next message. E.g., `"<key xyz part 1> ... 12345"`, followed by 
  `"<key xyz part 2> 67890 ..."`

**Multiple Event Types (with "irregular" content)**

- There are several types of events (20 to 50 prob.)
- The content of each event is different.
- The text of the event doesn't seem to follow any "fixed" pattern. It seems to contain free-text, key-value pairs with "=" separator and key-value pairs with ":" separator. Only thing that may help here is that "fields" (if you can call them that) are most often separated by ";".
- Some fields don't even have values.
- (I am not 100% sure but) it seems the payload (in terms of fields) can change even within the same message type.

Some examples (which I "obfuscated")

> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [011400\00]1/RncLmUePT(1/someResource[209]) ../filename.cpp:335 INFO:some_signal_name signal received in capsule nameOfSomething@someResource in state SomeEventName. This indicates a TYPE_OF_EXEPTION rasied in AnotherPlace.

Or these 5 messages, which are an example of multi-message event. Note the irregularity of the last message (it start slightly differently) and that 3rd and 4th messages are cut "mid-sentence"

> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [021100\01]2/PdcLmPrPT somefile.cc:172 INFO:< Segmenting traces for key 000001216649856, 4 parts will follow >
>
> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [021100\01]2/PdcLmPrPT somefile.cc:179 INFO:"ExceptionCode = 521; TIMER somename has expired; InterfaceTimout (Internal); Ueh;SomeCrypticName;No effect on connection;callProc = ProcedureNameX;DeviceRef = 2060; CLIENT_CODE = UNDEF; CLIENT_CODE2 = 1424514436 [0x54e85d84]; devId = 33456; devFroId = 871; prDevId = UNDEF; prDevFroId = UNDEF; spId = tc:p:225:1; typeModId = 20; "
>
> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [021100\01]2/PdcLmPrPT somefile.cc:179 INFO:"S-RNFF = 377540; causecode = UNDEF;No SOMETHING received;sourceType = devNoValid; sPJK=000000000000000000000000;targetType = someConnType; sPJK=000000000000000000000000;UE Cap = Rel9-00000000000000000000000000000010;fileName = ../anotherFileName.cpp;line = 9031;Previous state = someStateName;Current state ="
>
> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [021100\01]2/PdcLmPrPT somefile.cc:179 INFO:" WaitSomeOtherState;noOfSomeConnectionState = 459;noOfSomeResUsage = 598;ActiveDevId = [6548,-1,-1,-1,-1];ActiveDevFroId = [871,-1,-1,-1,-1];raTimerStatus = 0;raLaxTimerStatus = 0;procedureTriggerReason = someTypeOfRequest;lastGrabRule = NameOfGrabRule;Addition text = The EstablishmentCau"
>
> [2016-08-11 11:47:44.340] [021100\01]2/PdcLmPrPT(2/SOME_EXCEPTION) ../differentFile.cpp:4610 TRACE1:"se is Registration(12). Neither PPT Connection Setup Complete or POMP Link Restore Indication received.  "

I thought to put this data into Elastic Search for visualization (kibana) etc and I am not sure whether logstash is the tool for the job (or at least, the existing codec/plugins/filters). **I am open to hear of other/better frameworks as well**

From what I've read/understood so far, for a more "regular" data I'd be using multi-line codec and grok filter with simple elastic output plugin, but here I don't see that these tools are a viable option. (Am I correct in my assessment?)

What I thought of is maybe try to code some logstash plugin myself or process the trace with a standalone program.

Any thoughts or idea how I can use existing tools or alternatively, what would be a good approach for this scenario?

P.S. I have no experience with Ruby but quite fluent with java/js/python and .NET (C#)

P.S.2 I am not 100% locked on ELK. It seems one of the most common tools for such a job. I consider TSDBs or even column/document DBs as an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the multi line messages are not sequential, you are going to have to write some kind of stateful parser that figures out how to stitch the messages together. If it was sequential, you could probably use logstash grok patterns to figure out the beginning and end of each message.

An alternative approach is to simply use a grok pattern to extract the message id and add that as an attribute to the log message. Then you will end up with separate messages in Elasticsearch. However, in your Kibana dashboard, you could easily restrict your searches to a message id to get all the events related to a message id. This might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: In the settings above, would relaxing the order issue (assuming they are sequential), a multiline filter can handle it?

Comment: if you can come up with a regex, it should be doable with logstash

Answer (score 0):

You can write a ruby filter which performs combination of grep/sed/awk to grab the required data from input file and keep that data as an event. Drawback here is that, you need to have a file persisted in memory to perform the operation.

filter
{

```
 ruby {
code => 'require "open3"
         file_path = event.get("file_path")
         cmd =  "my_filter.sh -f #{file_path}"
         stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
         event.set("process_result", stdout.read)
         err = stderr.read
         if err.to_s.empty?
           filter_matched(event)
         else
           event.set("ext_script_err_msg", err)
         end'
  remove_field => ["file_path"]
```

}
   }